# Pygame - can't draw image to screen: TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a box to my screen, however when I call the function to do so it says I'm missing the argument for "surface"

As seen in the code below, the function is in a class. The function contains two parameters: "self" and "surface", and I'm passing the variable "screen" in place of "surface" so I can draw the box:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
(width, height) = (600, 400)
bg_colour = (100, 20, 156)

class infoBox(object):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.box = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255),(0,400,400,100),2)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.box)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("battle EduGame")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.display.flip()

gameRun = True


while gameRun:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the "x" is pressed
       pygame.quit() #quit game
       gameRun = False #break the loop.
       quit()

    screen.fill(bg_colour)

    infoBox.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.update()


    clock.tick(60)
```

I've done things exactly like this in previous codes however it's choosing not to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your calling technique:

```
class infoBox(object):

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.box)
...

infoBox.draw(screen)
```

`draw` is an instance method, but you've invoked it as a class method.  Therefore, you have only *one* argument, `screen`.  You haven't provided the required `self` instance ... which will be needed immediately.

You need to create the object and use *that* to invoke the routine, something like

```
game_box = InfoBox(screen)
...
game_box.draw(screen)
```